# Removing Nth node breaks when trying to remove head

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to remove a node at Nth position. For some reason, when trying to remove the head, the function errors out at `previous->next = current->next`. I've tried adding a condition to check if `previous->next != NULL`, but that didn't work. Can anyone hint out what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this? Thanks.

```
void removeNth(List** myList, int n) {
    Node* previous;
    Node* current;
    int count;

    if (getLength(*myList) >= n) {
        if (getLength(*myList) == n) {
            removeLast(myList);
        }
        else {
            previous = NULL;
            current = *myList;
            count = 1;

            while (count < n) {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
                count++;
            }

            previous->next = current->next;
            freeNode(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a special case for `n == 1`. A hint about your problem: What do you think `previous` points to when `n == 1`?

Comment: Out of curiousity, is `List` just a typedef alias for `Node`? because it sure looks that way from here. if it isn't, that `current = *myList` make no sense at all. if it is, why have `List` at all ?

Comment: Oh, and you *did* run your program in a debugger? Because then you would be able to see the values of all involved variables and would immediately see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I see, your `List` is just an alias for `Node`. Given that, you have what appears to be a single-forward-linked list, and given a head pointer and a count `n`, want to delete the 1-based positional node if it exists.

**The Task**

That pointer to the head pointer and realizing what it holds (the address of *a pointer*) is what makes this algorithm simpler than you're making it out to be. Initially it holds the address of the pointer that points to the first node in the list (or NULL if the list is empty). From there you need to walk it down the list, storing the address of the `next` pointer within the current node pointed-to for each hop you take. When you arrive at your counter limit, if it is still referring to a pointer to some `next` in the list, that pointer is pointing to your victim node (which may be the head node, but that doesn't really matter). You simply wire that pointer to the following node, then delete the now-orphaned item.

**The Code**

I've removed the `List` alias, as I honestly see no sense in it. If you were using a containing `List` structure with a `head` and `tail` pointer for faster end-inserts it would make more sense, but I see no such hint in any of your code for that to be the case. In fact, `current = *myList;` would not work at all unless `List` and `Node` were synonymous.

```
void removeNth(Node** pp, unsigned int n)
{
    // we're 1-based positioned, so leave early on a value of zero.
    //  for 0-based positioning delete these two lines.
    if (n-- == 0)
        return;

    // walk the list until (a) we run out of nodes, or (b) meet our count.
    while (*pp && n--)
        pp = &(*pp)->next; // save address of current node's next ptr

    // if this is still non-null, it means we have a prospect to free
    if (*pp)
    {
        Node *node = *pp;   // remember node we're about to orphan
        *pp = node->next;   // wire up next node to where that came from
        freeNode(node);     // now free the orphaned node
    }
}
```

I **strongly** advise you read this carefully and run it under a debugger, stepping through it and examining variables (and their addresses) to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

void removeNth(List** myList, int n) 
{

```
Node* previous;

Node* current;
int count;

if(n==1 && getLength(*myList)>=1) // This small change for deletion at beginning
{
   *myList=(*myList)->next;
   return;
}
else if (getLength(*myList) >= n)
{
    if (getLength(*myList) == n) {
        removeLast(myList);
    }
    else {
        previous = NULL;
        current = *myList;
        count = 1;

        while (count < n) {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
            count++;
        }

        previous->next = current->next;
        freeNode(current);
    }
}
```

}